# Weird Javascript TypeError 'is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a weird JS TypeError:

```
TypeError: $(...).formset is not a function
added: function(row) {
```

Now, the JS looks like this:

```
$('#richtextcontent_set-group .inline-related').formset({
  prefix: "richtextcontent_set",
  addText: "Text hinzufügen",
  formCssClass: "dynamic-richtextcontent_set",
  deleteCssClass: "inline-deletelink",
  deleteText: "Entfernen",
  emptyCssClass: "empty-form",
  removed: updateInlineLabel,
  added: function(row) {
    initPrepopulatedFields(row);
    reinitDateTimeShortCuts();
    updateSelectFilter();
    updateInlineLabel(row);
  }
});
```

It really can't be the `.formset()` call. If I execute

```
$('#richtextcontent_set-group .inline-related').formset({})
```

in the console, it doesn't return any errors.

And the `added:` option obviously receives a function.

I'm using the django-dynamic-formset plugin:
http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/

So what could be the problem here?

I will happily provide more information if necessary. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

The django inlines.js (containing `formset()`) really wasn't loaded due to a messy monkeypatch on the InlineModelAdmin that was overriding it's media property. Thanks for the comments and answer.

Comment: Perhaps this script is placed before the one that loads the formset plugin.

Comment: But then why would it point to the line number where the `added` option is?

Comment: Comment out the lines in the object and see which one of them is triggering the error.

Comment: Multiple jQuery instances on the page? Who knows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to log the output just before the offending code.

```
var formset = $('#richtextcontent_set-group .inline-related').formset;

// have a look at formset
console.log(formset);

formset({
    ...
    configuration properties
    ...
});
```

If `undefined` is returned to the console the plugin is not loaded at the time you're calling it. In that case it's best to execute your code when the dom is ready. This example wraps it inside `$(function() { ... })` to do exactly that.

```
$(function () {
    $('#richtextcontent_set-group .inline-related').formset({
        ...
        configuration properties
        ...
    }));
});
```

Now you're almost certain it's executed when to plugin is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved the problem, see the update above form more information.